# Angular 2 click event is not firing on dropdown button item on mobile/tablet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
   <div class="fbtn-inner">
      <button class="fbtn waves-attach waves-circle waves-effect" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>
     <div class="fbtn-dropdown">
       <button class="fbtn waves-attach waves-circle waves-effect" (click)="onAddContact()">
        <span class="fa fa-users"></span>
        <span class="fbtn-text fbtn-text-left">Add contact</span>
       </button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the dropdown is opened but the **click** event on the button is not firing only for mobile/tablet devices, but works perfectly on desktop browser.

Any idea why?

Comment: Doesnt seems any problem with me till now of `click` event in browser of mobile. Its works fine with multiple platforms

Comment: Can you post a reproducible sample?

Comment: PS: there's a problem in last span element

Comment: You are not closing your div's correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Check width or height of button and div. Might be in mobile devices button is overlapped with any element that's why it's not working.